# upload and save video from api with UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8.3

I have a video that is displayed through the one api in my application. I want to upload and save it on my device and I am using this code:

```
- (IBAction)saveMovie:(id)sender {

    NSString *path = @"http://development.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/f1a97ec0-e47f-470e-96a6-de98d2235dd0/Biceps.mp4";

    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(path)){
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(path, nil, nil, nil);
        [self alert];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"incompatible video");
    }
}
```

The link "path" is a own link to upload the file but also have the view link.

When I call the method that receives an answer

```
Video http://development.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/f1a97ec0-e47f-470e-96a6-de98d2235dd0/Biceps.mp4 cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x1660f300 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///http:/xerofit-development.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/f1a97ec0-e47f-470e-96a6-de98d2235dd0/Biceps.mp4, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///http:/xerofit-development.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/f1a97ec0-e47f-470e-96a6-de98d2235dd0/Biceps.mp4, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x16542030 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSURL=file:///http:/xerofit-development.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/f1a97ec0-e47f-470e-96a6-de98d2235dd0/Biceps.mp4}
```

what's wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it from NSTemporaryDirectory and it worked. It seems that if one accepts this way.

In my case I put this url

`http://qa-elb-765904057.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/plugin/execute?pluginName=xxxx&pluginMethod=xxxx&clientId=b0007920-88b4-11e5-a62a-fxxxxx&token=xxx94d60-91xx-11e5-a62a-f362d1d2xxx0&file_key=Mbxxx5v6RxxxQOR.mp4`

and the error was this

`Video /plugin/execute cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x176644e0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///plugin/execute, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///plugin/execute, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x17661850 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSURL=file:///plugin/execute}`

It seems that the entire url that was sending only detected this

`/plugin/execute`